Estoy lanzando wildFly-34 en IntelliJ y mi software no puede acceder a los recursos
IntelliJ crea el artefacto .JAR perfectamente, como se indica en la configuración, pero no lo despliega en el servidor de aplicaciones configurado en el IDE.
En su lugar, parece que IDEA está utilizando una sandBox para ejecutar wildFly.
Los beans se instancian perfectamente como indica el logo del servidor, pero los recursos no son accesibles, ya que nunca están en los directorios devueltos por getClass().getResourceAsStream()
